# css z-index issue with child element

Tags: css, z-index

I almost have the same problem as this one:

But i can not use his solution. I must set every thing visable. suppose i have this code:

```
<body>
    some information
    <div style="position:fixed;width:100%;height:100%;background-color:green;z-index: 2;opacity: 0.7"></div>
    <div style='z-index:1;background-color:white;position:fixed'>
        test1
        <div style='z-index:3;background-color:red'>
            test2
        </div>

    </div>      
</body>
```

My opinion is the mask div is over the body, and the parent div. the parent div is over the body. In the parent div there is a child div which is over mask and his parent and ofcourse the body. Mask, parent and child are all position:fixed, the body is relative. Well , i just can not set them whatever i change theire position type or z-index. only if i do not set the z-index of parent, then the child will correctlly over the mask, but if not, they all behind the mask.

Comment: i set mask, parent, child to the same position type: relative, absolute, fixed. Well, when they all are absolute, they works, but when they all are fixed or relative, no.

Comment: well, even all in absolute,they do not work.

Comment: I just can not believe this problem. All aticle say z-index is easy to understand, but why i just can not make this simple example works.

Answer (score 1):

In order for `z-index` to take affect an element must be positioned.  Also lower the z-index of your mask and increase the `z-index` of test1.  I would also recommend not inlining the styles, however I suspect this may be for the example.

```
<div style="position:fixed;width:100%;height:100%;background-color:green;z-index: 1;opacity: 0.7"></div>
<div style='z-index:2;background-color:white;position:fixed'>
    test1
    <div style='z-index:3;background-color:red; position:relative;'>
        test2
    </div>

</div>
```

Working Example: http://jsfiddle.net/vQz6P/

Comment: @ferdinandfly Check my update which suggests changing the z index on the mask and test1

Comment: Thanks a lot, but it does not work. inline style is not what i want, it's just an example. I need mask in front of test1, but behind test2. So the order of the mask, parent and child must be : 2, 1,3.

Comment: Couldn't you just separate the `test1` and `test2` in the markup so that they are siblings?

Comment: In fact, if i do not set parent's z-index, it works, but i need parent in front of the body, so i can not set parent z-index to void.

Comment: no, i can not separate them, in fact the idea is : i have a complex float bar, in the float bar, i have some buttons, when i click on the button, i have a tab show in. At this moment, i need to mask all other buttons except the orignal one. So, you see i can not seperate them.